# For each item in dictionary, create a column with incremental values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

For each item in dictionary, create a column with incremental values.

For ex:

```
new_dict = {"Class": list(set(df["Class"]))}
```

This dictionary will have distinct Class values, i need to add a column in my dataframe which will contact incremental values.

Let say, Class has: Class1, Class2, Class3
I need a column which will have 1, 2, 3 respectively..

Comment: so, `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Do you mind providing an [mcve]? Your explanation is not clear or helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer to my own question..

new_df['ClassId'] = pd.factorize(new_df.ClassId)[0] + 1

factorize can solve the problem here..

Comment: But what is the problem? You have not made anything clear here.